# The compiler shows a syntax error in this kivy python code. But I don't find any

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am doing a simple kivy project. But I can't get rid of a syntax error.

Here's the kivy code:

```
<shipBP>:
    size: 40,40
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: 40,40
            pos:self.pos

<game>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, self.height-20
            size: self.width,20
         
    shipBP:
        center: self.parent.center
```

The compiler says:

```
center: self.parent.center
           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Kivy Language Documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file) says:

> Keep class names capitalized to avoid syntax errors.

Just change `shipBP` classname to `ShipBP`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I was following the C++ way and didn't know that class names should be capitalised. :D